# get a order of sortable item in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Code works perfectly. Is it possible to track sortable item order and store in a variable each and every time an item changes position.

```
$('div.divContent ul').sortable({

    'remove': function(event, ui) {

    },
    'create': function(event, ui) {
        if ($(".widget-placeholder ui-droppable")); {

        }

    },
    'placeholder': 'div.divContent ul',
    'cursor': 'crosshair',
    'connectWith': 'div.divContent ul',
    'start': function(event, ui) {

        $(".widget-placeholder ui-droppable").disableSelection();
        $(ui.droppable).remove();

    },

    'stop': function(event, ui) {
        if ($('div.divContent ul').length)) {


        }
    },
    'cancel': function(event, ui) {


    },
    'sort': function(event, ui) {

        if ($('ul li').length) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try using the .sortable('serialize') function in the update() method (Your li's need to have an id like "order_<id>")? You should be able to save that in a variable that is defined in a more public scope.

Comment: @Thorsten may you have any sample code or link about `.sortable('serialize')`.If u have plz share.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at the official jQueryUI sortable docs, tab "methods". And at http://jsfiddle.net/Nt2wZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('li').index(ui.item);
```

to get the position of the current item. You must now choose which event to use this in.

Comment: thanks a lot.i got a solun inside your ans.`var modules = $(this).parent('ul').find('li');
                                alert(modules.length);
                                $.each(modules, function(index, item) {
                                    alert($(this).html()+"--"+$(this).index());
                                });`.this is a solution for future if any one search for the same problem.